# ¿Sería correcto usar la anotación @Autowired para inyectar de una clase Implementación y no del Service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, inyeccion-de-dependencias, annotation

Estoy usando el @Autowired en el controlador y la clase que estoy inyectando es la de la implementación, sería correcto esto?

Típicamente he visto que se hace de la interface service.

El resultado que obtengo es el mismo pero tengo dudas de si es correcto hacer esto o no.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Lee [ask].

Comment: Cuál opinión? Si estoy consultando una duda pues

Comment: "Sería correcto" es una pregunta subjetiva.